# Move a DOM element to an arbitrary position without mutating the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to move an element to a position in a variable without changing the value in the DOM?

For example, if I was using a div to represent a patrolling guard unit could I tell it where to move without having to force the entire DOM tree to recreate?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with *"moving"*. Position on the screen? Or index in some Array/NodeList? `could I tell it where to move without having to force the entire DOM tree to recreate?` I hope so, this would have a huge impact on your performance.

Comment: Everything in javascript is Object. so copy the DOM object in java script vaiable then attach it some other DOM location where ever you needed . var para = document.createElement("to");
var node = document.getElementById("from");
para.appendChild(node);

or I didn't get your question.

Comment: @Thomas sorry I meant moving it on screen. I've seen examples for moving elements using css animations but none that could have the destination specified rather than just going to the same direction every time.

Comment: the only solution I could think of was editing the transition for each movement,  but I'd rather not edit elements unnecessarily

Comment: take a look at [GreenSock](https://greensock.com/) or [VelocityJS](http://velocityjs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was misunderstanding reflow and what can cause it; I thought setting the *top* or *left* attributes would cause reflow however I've investigated since and found they won't.

So, to answer my question: to move a div from one position to another (arbitrary position) on a webpage you can:

1. Create a transition in CSS for that object (in the form: **transition: attributeToActOn lengthOfTimeToTake**, so for moving my div I used *top* and *left*.
2. Change the attributes you referenced in your transition to reflect your desired new position (and remember it will take exactly the **lengthOfTime** you defined).

Your element will gracefully move from the old position to the new
    one.

These transitions can be made more 'natural' by using cubic-bezier (or similar) functions for timing.